# Can I return a value from a component to change a component state from another?

Tags: reactjs

Change the value of a state when you click on the button to change the value of a state of another component.
Let me explain better with code

```
<div className="App-body">
   <PopularSelections value={this.state.selection}/>
</div>
```

and the component PopularSelections

```
export class PopularSelections extends React.Component {
    render (){
        return(
            <div className="PopularSelections">
                <button className={this.props.value === 'popular' ? "SelectionOn" : 'SelectionOff'}>Popular</button>
                <button className={this.props.value === 'upcoming' ? "SelectionOn" : 'SelectionOff'}>Upcoming</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So when I use for example `onClick` in one button of `PopularSelections`, I change the state of the first component, in this case the variable named `selection`, can I change it?

Comment: the 'selection' variable is in the component that calls <PopularSelections/>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a function in parent component which can change the state.

```
updateSelection = (value) => {
    this.setState({selection:value}, ()=>console.log(this.state.selection))
}
```

Pass this function to child component,

```
<PopularSelections value={this.state.selection} updateSelection={this.updateSelection}/>
```

In child component you can call that function,

```
<button className={this.props.value === 'popular' ? "SelectionOn" : 'SelectionOff'} onClick={()=>this.props.updateSelection("popular")}>Popular</button>

<button className={this.props.value === 'upcoming' ? "SelectionOn" : 'SelectionOff'} onClick={()=>this.props.updateSelection("upcoming")}>Upcoming</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xnaaft)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in the Parent component:

```
updateData=(data)=>{
    this.setState({selection:data})
}
```

Pass the function as a prop to the PopularSelections component:

```
<div className="App-body">
  <PopularSelections 
    value={this.state.selection}
    updateData={this.updateData}
   />
</div>
```

Now within PopularSelections:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.updateData("clicked")}>
    Click me!
</button>
```